# Should I use nullable types for Id's on my Entity Objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, nullable, entity-framework-4

**My current setup**:
I have an entity object with some properties, among them an `int Id`. To communicate with the database, I've created a repository with, among others, the following method:

```
public int Add(TEntity entity)
{
    ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
    return entity.Id;
}
```

(It's a generic repository, that requires that `TEntity` is a `class`, and that it implements `IEntity`, which is just an interface with an `int Id` property.)

**My problem:**
Now, when I want to create a new entity for adding to the repository, I need to give it an id. However, that doesn't allow EF to automatically generate the id for me, since it will already have a value.

**Possible solutions:**
I have only been able to think of these two possibilities.

1. Make the `Id` property nullable
2. Pass an `EntryInputModel` to the repository instead, and then do the mapping there.
   Currently I'm binding to `EntryInputModel` in my Controller, and mapping it to an `Entry` using [AutoMapper](http://codeplex.com/automapper). If I need to change this, I also need to re-think the dependencies in my project, since the `...InputModel` and `...ViewModel` classes are currently only available to my Web application.

**Which is preferable? Are there more ways to counter this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server as the backend, my recommended solution would be to make the ID column an INT IDENTITY on the database, and a not-nullable column in your entity object.

When adding a new entity, assign the ID some arbitrary value, like -1 or something, or no value at all, even. The actual ID will be generated automatically by SQL Server when you insert the new entity (

```
EntityContext.AddToEntities(newEntity);
EntityContext.SaveChanges();
```

and it will be automagically be signalled back to EF so you'll be able to use it right away once it's inserted:

```
int newEntityID = newEntity.ID;
```

Works like a charm - at least in my test apps :-)

Comment: I haven't actually created the DB yet. How do I reflect this behavior in a unit test of the Add() method on the repository?

Comment: @Tomas: if you need to mock this, you need to set the identity field to a valid value when the .SaveChanges() is called

Comment: @marc: As you see in the Add method above, I actually don't have the call to SaveChanges() in there. Does that mean that it's impossible to get the new id back from it?

Comment: @Tomas: if you use server-generated ID's (IDENTITY fields), those will only ever be generated when the data is actually inserted, e.g. when you call `SaveChanges()`

Comment: @marc: I think the issue is actually myself being stupid. What I should do is to pass the entity to the repository and add it, then call SaveChanges on my UnitOfWork (which in this case is a wrapper around the ObjectContext) and then just use the entity's id property where I need it. Since it's not in the DB, EF (or rather SQL Server) will assign new id regardless of its current one when I save it. Right? In other words, in my tests I only need to make sure that the AddObject method is called from Add, and that SaveChanges propagates properly. Do I need to test anything else in the controller?

Comment: @marc, I have another follow-up question: I'm using the code-only/model-first approach, and I can't make EF map the column to be marked IDENTITY as you suggest. Could you please take a look at this post to see if you have any suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603148/map-a-column-to-be-identity-in-db-with-ef4-code-only

Comment: That problem is now solved. Thanks a lot for your help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

you can have generated unique id's that are not generated by the datastore/EF, allowing you to define them before passing the object into EF... (think of Guid's)

Comment: However, I'd like to use `int`s for id, to be able to use them in url's without loosing so much readability.